# My group (according to /bin/id) has rw access to a Char device but access is denied

Tags: linux

I am in the group `graphics`

```
shell@lt03wifi:/ $ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),1009(mount),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0
```

The char device `/dev/graphics/fb0` is marked as accessible (rw) to my group:

```
shell@lt03wifi:/ $ ls -l /dev/graphics/fb0                         
crw-rw---- root     graphics  29,   0 2013-12-24 23:30 fb0*
shell@lt03wifi:/ $ mount | grep "/dev "
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,size=1421696k,nr_inodes=114626,mode=755 0 0
```

But I am denied access (why ?):

```
shell@lt03wifi:/ $ cd data/data/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside/files/system/bin
shell@lt03wifi:/data/data/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside/files/system/bin $ ./grep -l . /dev/graphics/fb0
grep: /dev/graphics/fb0: Permission denied
```

The test executable `grep` works, see:

```
shell@lt03wifi:/data/data/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside/files/system/bin $ ./grep -l . grep
./grep
```

Why am I denied access to this char device ?

Comment: What do you intend to accomplish with `grep`ping from your frame buffer? Also, what are the permissions on `/`, `/dev` and `/dev/graphics`?

Comment: Have you tried the newgrp graphics command to change your default group?

Comment: @twalberg: `grep` is just a process opening the device for reading. I could have used `wc` or `cat`, but `grep -l` is the fastest in case of success and has small outputs, so it would not last long on computers of others trying to answer my question.

Comment: @twalberg: I tried to root a tablet with the open-source rooting method explained at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48818188

Comment: I noticed that your filesystem is mounted with seclabel, do you have SELinux enabled? (you may need to add a policy to allow your user context to access the context of the device) You can use `getenforce` to check.

Comment: KJ4IPS: how can I do that ? If you post instructions as an answer, this will surely be the answer that I will accept.